# SceneKit Project User Interaction

Tags: swift, macos, scenekit

I have been working on a game in SceneKit which involves a plane that the user can control using the arrow keys. The plane can fly, but the arrow keys have no effect on the plane. When I run a test to see if the arrow key function is working I can see that the arrow keys are effectively changing the speed of the plane, but the plane does not increase or decrease speed. Here is the code:

```
import SceneKit
import QuartzCore
class GameViewController: NSViewController {
var height = 0
var speed = 0 //I should be able to change this value by pressing the up arrow key during the simulation
override func keyDown(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
    if(theEvent.keyCode == 123){//left
    }
    if(theEvent.keyCode == 124){//right
    }
    if(theEvent.keyCode == 125){//down
    }
    if(theEvent.keyCode == 126){//up
        speed+=1
        print(speed)
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Plane.scn")!
    let cameraNode = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "camera", recursively: true)!
    let plane = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "plane", recursively: true)!
    plane.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: CGFloat(height), z: CGFloat(speed), duration: 1)))
    cameraNode.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.moveBy(x:0, y:CGFloat(height), z: CGFloat(speed), duration:1)))

    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
    }

}
```

Comment: Use the key event in the scene, not in the view controller.

Comment: When I move the function for the keyDown into the viewDidLoad function and remove the the override from the keyDown function, the computer does not respond to the keys at all. If a keep the override part, the computer returns an error.

Comment: Que!?  Your scene view has viewDidLoad?  Only the view controller has viewDidLoad.

Comment: It's view's (NSView, SCNView...) job to read events.

Comment: Let me see your scene view, then.

Comment: I suggest you read a book on SpriteKit or SceneKit basics.

Comment: Ok, I work some more research in. I coming from another programming language so I don't know the documentation yet. Thanks Anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have a created a `SCNAction` object with parameters that depend on the `speed` variable, any change to `speed` won't update the action.

This is because `speed` is a value type (`Int`) and there's no connection between the `SCNAction` instance and your view controller's `speed` instance variable. This is not an issue specific to SceneKit, any API that takes an `Int` as a parameter would behave the same way.

Comment: Now I know what the problem is, could you tell me how I could fix the problem. Should I change the variable type? How can I update the action so it responds? Thanks for your advice.